# Removing thin white line around view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have this thin white border around my tab bar views, its only in these views within the tab bar controller and not the rest of the app. image below, hopefully its visible that there is a border all the way around the left, right, bottom (top is covered by the nav bar)

[View Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43UWt.png)

Is there a clear cause for this behaviour? The UI is create in code rather than IB, im using an image as the background (code below), but im using the same image in other views not in the tab view and it fits fine so its not related to the image being too small. No borders are being added in the code or anything.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"effectsBackground"]]];
```

Im short of ideas as to why this is only happening in the tab bar controller views and not elsewhere?

Update: Reveal screenshot

[image: reveal shot]

Comment: You're using a UITabBarController as a ViewController contained by a UINavigationController? Have you used Debug View Hierarchy to figure out if it's actually a "thin white border" or if the tab bar content is not being sized as expected?

Comment: Theres no nav controller, its a tab bar controller thats kind of a pop over style thing, you open it with a button, then can click the tabs, or close the whole thing. I will add a reveal screenshot to the OP that highlights the view breakdown and may help

Comment: What is the frame / bounds of the highlighted UIView? And frame/bounds of its superview? and of the TabBar view and of the NavBar view? Based on your first image, it *looks* like the NavBar is fitting properly, but the "main view" and the TabBar view are inset by 1pt all the way around (hard to tell, but it looks like the same 1pt "line" along the bottom).

Comment: The white bordered view in the pic is a 'UILayoutContainerView' which apparently is apple created and i have no control over when i researched it. I didnt set any of it up. There is a white border at the bottom too yes. The selected view is a storyboard but its whole content is build via code and inits with a frame based on screenbounds

Comment: OK - *but* .... if the UILayoutContainerView has the 'white border' ... when you debug the running app, what are the values for its frame? and the frames/bounds of its subviews? If UILayoutContainerView is at `0,0 1024x768` and UIView is at `0,0 1024x768` and UIImageView is at `0,0 1024x768`, then how can the white border be showing ***through*** UIVIew and UIImageView? (and ***through*** the TabBar view?) Or... are the subviews actually `1,1 1022x766`?

Comment: I ran a print on the tab bar controller view and its 0,0,1024,768, its sub views (the tabs) are also the same as this size

Comment: If you use Debug View Hierarchy and check the bounds / frames of the "main" UIView and of the UITabBar, do you get the same values as seen here? https://imgur.com/a/hBnaU

Comment: yep every one of those background views is the same sizing